# emergency mode after nvidia driver 450 update for GTX750ti rev a2 (18.04.5 kernel 4.15)

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I ran an update which installed some new nvidia packages (this always make me nervous for some reason idk why*), anyway now when I try and boot up things seem normal until I get to the xubuntu splash then it crashes and drops me into the emergency mode root shell.

I tried adding `nomodeset` in grub to no effect.

I checked out `/var/log/dpkg.log` to get an idea of what in the last update might have caused an issue and the `libnvidia-*-450` packages seemed to have installed fine.

If I run `nvidia-smi` I get driver version 450.102.04 and no running processes so the driver seems to be installed but is not working for some reason.

In case it is relevant I have secure boot off.

I don't have a network connection from the emergency mode shell so I'm seeing if I can figure out how to connect so I can try rerunning updates from here to see if that fixes things otherwise. I'm not sure what to try next to troubleshoot this and get the ability to run my desktop environment back - any suggestions would be appreciated.

*[image]